# New review interface is not looking pretty good with lots of text

Tags: discussion, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, design

New review interface is not looking pretty good when there are a lot of text in editor's note. The buttons are moving to fit the text and therefore overlap each other.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: I was able to reproduce this on Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Do you have a link to the review task handy? It looks as if the problem is that the very long URL isn't getting wrapped.

Comment: @JonEricson Here it is: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/144270?filter-tags=android)

Comment: @JonEricson I tried it on a random suggestion, open the developer tools and just added more text (with spaces), and I saw the same result like the screenshot

Comment: @AlonEitan: Thanks. I'll make sure we talk about this on Monday. I don't think it'll be difficult to fix.

Comment: I think the problem is not in URL, it is in css

Comment: @sudo I believe Jon was referring the the URL left in the comments for the change; not the URL of the review. But yes, the CSS is broken in that it's not wrapping long URLs (or more generally, long unbroken words)